# Nested loops with matrix - why does this second matrix at all?

Tags: python, matrix, while-loop

This doesn't make sense to me yet. So the first while loop runs and prints matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2] and matrix[0][3] until j=4 and isn't less than `len(matrix[i])`. Okay, but now it pops out and goes back up to `while i<len(matrix):`. Wouldn't this make it read `j=0` again and go straight back into the nested while loop?

```
matrix = [[4,5,6,7],[2,4,9,3]]
i=0
while i<len(matrix):
    j=0
    while j<len(matrix[i]):
        print matrix[i][j]
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

Comment: i<len(matrix):. Wouldn't this make it read j=0 again and go straight back into the nested while loop?    Sorry that last sentence got cut off.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix the cut off sentence.

Comment: This prints `4 5 6 7 2 4 9 3`, which is what I expected it would do.  What did you think it would do?

Comment: After j isn't less than len(matrix[i]): it seems that the next line that's read is i=i+1, which owuld make while j<len(matrix[i]): be referring to matrix [1] rather than [0], I guess I overlooked that and thought it would got back to j=0 after reading the matrix[0].

Comment: In practice, you would probably be better off making use of a `for` loop. Especially if you take advantage of the iterable nature of lists.
`for row in matrix:`
`    for item in row:`
`        print item`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and that's exactly what it does.

See for yourself by adding a print statement:

```
matrix = [[4,5,6,7],[2,4,9,3]]
i=0
while i<len(matrix):
    j=0
    while j<len(matrix[i]):
        print 'i = {}, j = {}, element = {}'.format(i,j,matrix[i][j])
        print matrix[i][j]
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

---

By the way, that is a very unpythonic way to loop in python.  This is equivalent, and more suited to the language:

```
matrix = [[4,5,6,7],[2,4,9,3]]
for row in matrix:
  for element in row:
    print element
```